# How to randoming in specific row

Tags: matlab

I have created a matrix using this code:

```
row=4;
column=5;
pop=5;


for ii = 1:(row*pop)
    done = false;
    while ~done
        newRow = randi([0 2],column,1);
        done = (sum(newRow)<12)...
            && (~any(diff([0;find(newRow);column+1])>3));
    end
    result(:,ii) = newRow;
end
result = permute(reshape(result,column,row,pop), [2 1 3]);
```

I get a matrix result `(4,5,5)` and then I want to random again in specific row and pop that is caused by a constraint.

```
for ii=1:pop;
       while size(find(waktu_libur(:,:,ii)>20&waktu_libur(:,:,ii)<23),1)~=11, 
       %#condition that had to be fullfilled by matrix result.
       for bb=1:row;
           if find(waktu_libur(bb,:,ii)>20&waktu_libur(bb,:,ii)<23),
               continue;
           else
           done = false;
           while ~done
                newRow = randi([0 2],column,1);
                done = (sum(newRow)<12)...
                && (~any(diff([0;find(newRow);column+1])>3));
           end
           dummy = newRow;
           dummy= permute(reshape(dummy,jum_bag,1), [2 1]); %#this matrix which is used to replace
           result(bb:,ii)=dummy %#process replacing dummy to row in matrix result that still obey contraint.
           end %#end looping if
        end %# end looping for
     end %#end looping while
end %# end looping for
```

I think that my code is correct. But after running, it gives this error:

```
??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
```

Does anyone see what causes this error?

Comment: Hey Febri, there are several more things we'll need.  First make it clear that waktu_libur is the same as the "result" matrix you created in step 1.  Second, there's a rogue : in `result(bb:,ii)=dummy` and finally the variable jum_bag is undefined

Comment: When Matlab prints the error you can see the file and line where it was thrown. I suggest to set a breakpoint in that line and execute the program again. This way you can find out, which index runs out of bounds.

Comment: @Salain : Mr salain, look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009394/how-to-random-position-of-value-in-a-matrix, this is my question before, but no one understand what i want...

Answer (score 0):

After fixing these issues, the code runs fine:

1. I replaced `waktu_libur` by `result`.
2. A comma is missing in `result(bb:,ii)`
3. `jum_bag` is undefined in `reshape(dummy,jum_bag,1)`. However, as `reshape()` requires the number of input and output elements to be equal, the only possibility is to set `jum_bag = numel(dummy)`.

After these changes the code runs. Unfortunately, I could not reproduce your error.

However, there are some other things I would suggest to change:

1. Add a `clear result` at the beginning of your first code snippet. You do not initialize the output variable but build it dynamically (which is **slow**, by the way). Then you change the shape of `result`. If you re-execute the code, the dynamic creation does not work as there is already a `result` in memory with the wrong dimensions.
2. This code `newRow = randi([0 2],column,1);` creates a column vector. Thus the following `reshape(dummy,jum_bag,1)`, which also creates a column vector, is not needed.

Comment: actually, I have another matrix called "krom" that will be combined with matrix result, so then I will get matrix waktu_libur. then, from that matrix, I will try to find the best result and krom. do you understand?

Comment: @FebriDwiLaksono: Probably it would be easiest, if you provide a small `waktu_libur` and an exact copy of the code, which throws the error. The code for the creation of the `result` matrix is just distracting because you do not need that matrix anyway.